# Fill DataTable with two queries in C#

Tags: c#

I have multiple tables in a SQL Server database and I am trying to fill a `DataTable` with two queries on two tables.

This is my code:

```
String qry = "SELECT Count(*) FROM boss WHERE username ='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'; SELECT Count(*) FROM employee WHERE first_name ='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password ='" + textBox2.Text + "' "; 

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=my_pro;Integrated Security=True");

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

But this shows me data from `boss` table. What should I do?

Comment: how about select union select

Comment: Also, consider checking the user input before putting it in the query or you may meet [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  String qry = "SELECT Count(*) FROM boss WHERE username ='" + textBox1.Text +    
               "'and password ='" + textBox2.Text + "' UNION ALL  SELECT Count(*) FROM   
                 employee WHERE first_name ='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password ='" +  textBox2.Text + "' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the query,

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   boss 
        ) AS count1,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   employee 
        ) AS count2
 WHERE username ='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password ='" + textBox2.Text + "';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subquery

```
    SELECT  BossCount=(
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM   boss 
            WHERE username ='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'
            ) ,
            EmployeeCount=(
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM   employee 
            boss  WHERE first_name ='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'
            )
```